# VBA function that outputs all unique values on different cells in the same row in worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function (that when you pass it an array (Maybe a range is better?) that it outputs all the unique values in the same row on different cells.
I've gotten as far as knowing how to identify the elements (which I don't think I've done right :( ) but I'm not sure how I'd output all the unique values. I only get the first one.
My code is as follows:

```
    Function UniqueItems(ArrayIn, Optional Count As Variant) As Variant
 '   Accepts an array or range as input
'   If Count = True or is missing, the function returns the number of unique elements
'   If Count = False, the function returns a variant array of unique elements
Dim Unique() As Variant ' array that holds the unique items
Dim Element As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim FoundMatch As Boolean

'If 2nd argument is missing, assign default value
If IsMissing(Count) Then Count = True
'   Counter for number of unique elements
NumUnique = 0
'   Loop thru the input array
For Each Element In ArrayIn
    FoundMatch = False
'       Has item been added yet?
    For i = 1 To NumUnique
        If Element = Unique(i) Then
            FoundMatch = True
            Exit For '(exit loop)
        End If
    Next i
AddItem:
   'If not in list, add the item to unique list
    If Not FoundMatch And Not IsEmpty(Element) Then
        NumUnique = NumUnique + 1
        ReDim Preserve Unique(NumUnique)
        Unique(NumUnique) = Element
    End If

    Next Element 
 If Count Then UniqueItems = NumUnique Else UniqueItems = Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Function UniqueItems(ArrayIn) As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim vNewdata() As Variant
    Dim colUniques As Collection
    Dim lCt As Long
    If TypeName(ArrayIn) = "Range" Then
        vData = ArrayIn.Value
    Else
        vData = ArrayIn
    End If
    Set colUniques = New Collection
    'assuming a one-column range

    On Error Resume Next 'ignore duplicates

    For lCt = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        colUniques.Add vData(lCt, 1), CStr(vData(lCt, 1))
    Next
    ReDim vNewdata(1 To 1, 1 To colUniques.Count)
    For lCt = 1 To colUniques.Count
        vNewdata(1, lCt) = colUniques(lCt)
    Next
    UniqueItems = vNewdata
End Function
```

Comment: It's getting all unique values in a row not a column. Does that change anything?

Comment: To get everything in a column, change this line UniqueItems = vNewdata
 to UniqueItems = Application.Transpose(vNewdata)

Comment: when I use the function in the spread sheet I only get the first results in the cell I put the function in, not the full list of the unique array values in separate cells. So I've put the formula: =UniqueItems(Range()) in several cells and used ctrl+shift+enter. I only get the first result of the unique array. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make the suggested change I showed in my previous comment? Also, you must now control+shift+enter the formula in a set of rows, not in columns.

Answer (score 0):

you might use Scripting.dictionary to get unique value fast as for exemple

```
Sub TestArray()
Dim arrStart() As Variant
Dim oDic As Scripting.Dictionary

arr = Array(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)

Set oDic = uniquevalue(arr)

'Note : put data into array
Dim arrResult() As Variant
arrResult = oDic.Keys
'Note : put data into string
Dim stringResult As String
stringResult = Join(oDic.Keys, ";")
End Sub

Function uniquevalue(ByVal myArray) As Scripting.Dictionary
'Note : Add REF DLL Microsoft Srcipting Runtime before !!
'Note : Option base =0 (standard vbe param)
'Note : Array is mono dimension of any data type
Dim oDic As Scripting.Dictionary
Set oDic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If Not oDic.Exists(myArray(i)) Then oDic.Add myArray(i), oDic.Count
    Next i

Set uniquevalue = oDic
End Function
```